# Ordering of a 2D array

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem on 2D arrays and need little help. The problem goes like this:

Suppose we have a 2D array A of size nxn comprising of unique elements. The need to rearrange the elements of A as follows. Let A11, A12, A21, A22 be four mutually disjoint subarrays of A, each of size n/2 x n/2. Then A11 < A12 < A21 < A22. If each of these subarrays is recursively split into four equal-sized sub-arrays, then also the property holds.

User input: n, N (≥ n2). n is a power of 2

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Nearly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882083/generation-and-ordering-in-a-2d-array/6882282#comment-8190935. There is still the same flaw: You will have to explain what the sentence "Then A11 < A12 < ..." is supposed to mean. Otherwise I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: You tried many things? What did you try? Does this have anything to do with C? Do you have any code to show us? Or should this go to math.stackexchange.com? etc. etc.

Comment: Is `n` a multiple of 2 or a power of 2?

Comment: @Kerrek, it's a power of two, linked question confirms that.

Comment: @whoplisp: A11 < A12 < A13 < A14 means that all elements in subarray are < all elements of A12. As an example consider a 4x4 array with following elements... Row 1:   1 2 5 8

Comment: There is another closed version of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844013/dynamic-generation-of-a-2d-array-filling-with-unique-random-nos-and-ordering-th

Comment: @rits that still doesn't make sense to me. Could you maybe describe in your own words what the problem is, that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @whoplisp: A11 < A12 < A13 < A14 means that all elements in subarray are < all elements of A12. As an example consider a 4x4 array with following elements... Row 1:   1 2 5 8   Row 2: 3 4 9 11  Row 3: 13 14 19 22  Row 4: 16 18 29 34. Now Subarray A11 is a 2x2 array with elements Row1: 1 2, Row2: 3 4. Similarly A12 has following elements Row1: 5 8, Row2: 9 11. and so on for other subarrays. As you can see all elements of A11 < A12. Hope this makes the picture more clearer.

Comment: @Kerrek: its a power of 2...my mistake in posting

Comment: @ritz okay. Now I get your question. You want to convert a random matrix into one that has the ordering structure you described.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function which will convert an index between 0 and n*n-1 to coordinates in your array according to the ordering in question. Then you just run some usual 1D sorting algorithm, on an array of size n*n, `j`th element of which is substituted using that function. It solves the problem.

Update: the mapping function maps numbers in this matrix to their coordinates:

```
 0  1  4  5
 2  3  6  7
 8  9 12 13
10 11 14 15
```

Comment: I thought of that but dont seem to understand how to do it recursively for subarrays within the subarrays.

Comment: @rits, that mapping function can be recursive. Just draw some examples of mapping.

Comment: @unkulunkulu You're referring to sorting the array and then filling the matrix along a [z-order curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) I assume?

Comment: @Bart, yes! This is a perfect way to reformulate this, I think you should create a separate answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking somewhat on the answer of unkulunkulu I think you could approach it as follows:

Take all the values in your matrix (2D) and put them in a simple array (1D). Then take this array and sort the values from lowest to highest.

Now what you need to do is fill the matrix again but in such a way that it conforms to the rules you have specified. If you have a look at a [Z-order space filling curve in 2D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), you will find that if you fill you matrix in this order (with the sorted elements), that the resulting matrix has your desired properties.

Now actually coding this would be up to you.

Answer (score 1):

The book numerical recipes chapter 21.8 http://www.nrbook.com/nr3/ gives an analytic expression to calculate an index into the 2D array given the coordinates of a quadtree.

[image]
[image]

Here is another straight forward approach that I tried, but I don't like it as much:

```
(defun quad-pos (pos)
  "POS is a list of letters that indicate the position in a 2x2 matrix [a,b; c,d]."
  (let ((x 0)
    (y 0)
    (s 1))
    (dolist (e pos)
      (setf s (/ s 2))
      (ecase e
    ('a )
    ('b (incf x s))
    ('c (incf y s))
    ('d (incf x s) (incf y s))))
    (values x y)))
#+nil
(quad-pos '(a)) ;=> 0, 0
#+nil
(quad-pos '(a b c)) ;=> 1/4, 1/8
#+nil
(quad-pos '(d d d d)) ;=> 15/16, 15/16
```